# come across or comes across

Tags: grammar

I am just wondering if the below statement is grammatically correct. I'm confused if it should be 'come across' or 'comes across'

He is one individual, who come across very calm and composed in any situation

Thanks

Comment: It should definitely be *comes*, as it has to agree with *one individual*. But you also need an *as* in there. *He comes across as very calm*. The *as* does get elided but I believe the speaker's style suffers as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Individual” is singular, so:

> He is one individual, who **comes** across very calm and composed in any
>   situation.

But, this is seemingly a defining relative clause, so:

> He is one individua**l w**ho comes across very calm and composed in any
>   situation.

Further:

> He is one individual who comes across **as** very calm and composed in any
>   situation.